# Why does this cause memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm new to Objective-C, and I've read some memory management articles but am having trouble.

I hava a class something like this:

```
-(UIWebView*)getWebView{
    //UIWebView* webview = [UIWebView initWithFrame:self.frame];  edited,the original wrong line
    UIWebView* webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]; 
    return webview; 
}
-(void)addToSelf{
    UIWebView* view = [self getWebView];
    [self addSubview:view];
    [view release];  //release here
}
```

In my thought, objc objects are all like C pointers (it is ?) 
And thinking like this:

```
UIWebView* webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];  //retain +1
UIWebView* view = [self getWebView];  //just a pointer to the same object ?
[self addSubview:view]; //retain +1
[view release];   //retain -1
```

Now view's `retainCount = 1`.
Then this viewController will handle the webview's life cycle.

There must be something wrong with my thought (sure also the code), 
**but I don't know why** .

```
UIWebView* webview = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame] autorelease];
```

When I remove the last release line, code works fine, why? 
**What's the difference?**

--------------edit line---------------

Few minutes ago , there's an answer about it but it's disappeared , now I rewrite my thought:

The answer says:

When returning object from method , i must use **autorelease** to tell compiler I have end with it, and then using addSubview , finish (no need releasing).

I know this is right , but why it's right ?

In most of codes:

```
-(void)someMethod{
    UIWebView* webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]; 
    [self addSubview:webview];
    [webview release];
}
```

this works fine, but when separate the code to two methods like the top ,it's not.

Why i must use **autorelease** when returning object?

Comment: careful with name conventions: only methods with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” are not autorelease. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: It would be very confusing if you keep counting retainCount in your head. Generally, what you need is just making sure all variables that still in the scope is still retained, and release all variables before they get out of scope. There are few exception for this though, e.g. delegate and return value, and I suggest that you find some example and study them.

Comment: You don't have to autorelease the return value. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: FWIW, is this really your code, or did you leave out something? Could it be that something else in your class releases the webView? FWIW, your local variable *view* might hide any ivar with the same name, but I don't see how that could cause your error.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis , use xcode's Analyse checking project, it tells me the codes have retain issues, after adding autorelease , warning and memory leaks disappeared .

Comment: Well, it is indeed **better** code to autorelease in `getWebView`, and omit the `release` in `addToSelf`, and that is what *Analyse* is telling you, but what you do should not cause a crash, unless you do **both** at the same time: autorelease in `getWebView` and release in `addToSelf`.

Comment: Yes, since `autorelease` does the right thing , `release` should be right. since fix all issues just by adding `autorelease` and this let me thinking there should not be issues with other codes. I'll review codes and post origin codes here.(all codes are storing in company's Mac)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if you don't alloc the UIWebView:

```
UIWebView* webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
```

That means you probably don't have a valid UIWebView, and a retain count that is undefined, since the code for UIWebView is actually using some unknown piece of memory. If this works, you are lucky.

Comment: Sorry , It's a typo . In project **alloc** is called.

Comment: A **typo**? Please always post your **actual** code, copied from Xcode and pasted into the browser, not something you type into your browser.

Comment: Sorry, am I missing something? The line you've copied from OP *does* alloc the `UIWebView`, does it not?

Comment: @dcrosta: I didn't copy that, the original version did **not** alloc the UIWebView. Take a look at the edits of the question: The original was: `UIWebView* webview = [UIWebView initWithFrame:self.frame];`

Comment: Ah, I see now. Apologies, I'm just glad I wasn't going crazy over here!

Answer (score 1):

Your general idea of how retains and releases balance each other is correct. When you remove that last retain call, you are leaking. This is a defect that won't be noticeable unless you're observing memory use. (Leaks are important on any computer, but have a greater impact on handheld devices.)

In practice, if a method creates (`alloc`) and returns an object, `autorelease` it. The caller can then just use that object, and not worry about its lifetime.

Comment: While that is true, it does not explain his problem. He does not autorelease, so `addToSelf` should release `view`.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis , Yes,yes,this is the point confusing me , I must have to learn English hardly .

Comment: kran, are you crashing with the `release` line? You never said so.

Comment: @Jon Reid , Not crash with `release` line. But add `autorelease` can fix the problem , so I'm confused.

Comment: Was there a problem you observed, other than leaking?

Comment: Also `zombie` , this crash the application,  but also disappear after using `autorelease`

Comment: Basically, *something* has to call `release`, either by you or by `autorelease`. Both should work, but `autorelease` is the preferred method when you go from one method to another.

Comment: Yes,you're right , I'll use `autorelease` in the after . Now I want to find out what's the problem and maybe this will help me better understanding of Obj-C memory managements.

Comment: What is the problem? A crash?

Answer (score 0):

*#1: Method that 'alloc's should have the responsibility to call the release-statements on the object.

*#2: When you create a separate method to alloc an object for you, you cannot have 'release' statement, since that will release the object even before call site method uses it. Hence, instead of calling release we call autorelease and thus obeying the principal of #1, but still allowing call-site to use the object. As call-site didn't do any alloc by itself, it also does not have to worry about any releases.****

Comment: I don't understand point #2. While it is probably **better** to autorelease in `getWebView`, it does **not explain why he gets a crash** when he doesn't and releases in `addToSelf`.

Comment: Hmmm... does he actually get a crash? I'm not so sure anymore. If he is merely concerned about a leak or what Analyse tells him, the point is moot.